# Class has no attribute(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, web-scraping

I am new to classes and I am trying to follow freecodecamps' scraping course, however I am having problem instantiating an instance of Booking class:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver


class Booking(webdriver.Firefox):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"C:/SeleniumDrivers"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] = self.driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()
        
    def const_url(self, BASE_URL="https://www.booking.com/"):
        BASE_URL = self.BASE_URL

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(BASE_URL)
```

I've first tried to get BASE_URL from a constants file but had constant errors so I am creating everything in one file now.

```
booking = Booking()
with Booking() as bot:
    bot.land_first_page
```

When I try to run this code block above, it gives me AttributeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\AUIVVII\Udemy\AutomatingEV\BookingScraping\Booking\booking.py", line 23, in <module>
    bot.land_first_page
AttributeError: 'Booking' object has no attribute 'land_first_page'
```

It should have opened up the homepage of booking.com however, two headless firefox instances open up but nothing is loaded and one of them closes shortly after.

Edit: I've tried it with another website in case it had smth to do with booking's own system however the site doesn't matter. Also I don't get attribute error anymore but nothing is done in the end either

Edit2: Thanks to Andrej's answer, I got working but I still don't understand why it didn't work before(more detailed question in the comments)

Comment: Maybe you can try to call the method: `bot.land_first_page()` (note the `()`)

Comment: That wasn't the answer but it led me down to the correct one. When i added the (), it said BASE_URL not defined and I defined it under the land_first_page, now it's working. Could somebody answer why it couldn't get BASE_URL before?

Comment: @SarpYy it couldn't get BASE_URL because it is not defined in that method, as the error message said. If you are having difficulty understanding that I strongly suggest you read a book or watch a video on OOP in python or in general for all languages.

Comment: @DanielSabrel been interested in coding for years but never could actually grasp it. It's been a few days since I actually started understanding python so yeah, having a bit more fundamental knowledge seems to be what I urgently need rn. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've defined BASE_URl under the land_first_page method and added the parantheses while calling it. That seems to have finally made it work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).